# Difference between "Меня зовут Фёдор" и "Меня звать Фёдором"

Tags: падежи, выбор-имени, звать

What's the difference between "Меня зовут Фёдор" и "Меня Фёдором звать"?
At first I thought that the Nominal case ("Фёдор") is more appropriate for names and the Instrumental ("Фёдором") is for nicknames, but later I came across other examples.

[image]

**EDIT**: My question is not about WHETHER IT'S ONE OR TWO SUBJECTS in a Nominal constructions like "Меня зовут Анна", "Меня зовут Фёдор", etc. My question is about WHAT THE DIFFERENCE is between these two usages, that is, between "зовут Фёдор" and "звать Фёдором". So, it is not a direct duplicate of **[Regarding case usage with звать](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/13403/regarding-case-usage-with-%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)**, none of the three current answers of which are answering my question here (some comments come close, but not the answers).

Comment: Please let me bring your attention to an answer given in another thread **[Regarding case usage with звать](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/13405/7674)** In short, in my opinion the case stems here from the question word being implied - either `как?` or `кем?`

Comment: It's the difference between "people call me __" and "I am to be called __", literally speaking. Also, congrats on your choice of quality television.

Comment: @AntonLiakhovitch: "people call me __" is very common in English for self-introductions and sounds natural, while "I am to be called __" sounds very imperative, almost like an order. Are you saying that "Меня зовут Фёдор" and "Меня Фёдором звать" have same connotations in Russian?

Comment: yes they do, the Instrumental case however to me at least sounds more dialectical, although it's still normative, but the answer is that usage wise there's no difference, the form in the Instrumental case is less frequent and as it seems slowly but surely falling out of use, it will take a couple of generations... i would not be guided their literal translation to English because this is confusing and creates an deceptive impression of what's appropriate

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка: "the answer is that usage wise there's no difference" - Are you sure? It looks to me like "Меня Фёдором звать" wouldn't be used in an official setting, but "Меня зовут Фёдор" would.

Comment: to some extent it's true, because the Instrumental case sounds more folksy, but there're no rules so far as i'm aware

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка: I see. Thank you.